# How can serialize all ASTs into a file like PDOM in eclipse-cdt?(Not JavaModel)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I want to implement a `IDE-function` like `OpenDeclaration` in `Eclipse` with browser client.

My original thinking is importing java files into server and parse them using `JDT`. If I click a `method invocation` in a java file with browser, I can get corresponding `ASTNode` through filename and the offset.Then I can calculate `Declaration` Node using binding and convert it again for retrieving by browser.

The question is I can't find the real position about `binding` information and all `CompilationUnits`.

Comment: I don't know about PDOM, so I can't answer on that part, but as you mention a browser client, are you aware of the [Eclipse JDT Language Server](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls) project?

Comment: I need to run `standalone` files and get the result from `JDT AST` analysis. The search engine is `JDT` and I just use browser client to show the results.  The `OpenDeclaraton` feature is important in my demo. That's why I want to store ASTs into a file that I can show the demo if cache remove these ASTs.@StephanHerrmann

Comment: I find a class called `SearchRequestor`. I want to know is it suitable for standalone java files(not java model).@StephanHerrmann